# Error when running R script

Tags: r

When I run my R script, it gives me an error:

```
Error in list.files(lib, pattern = paste0("^", pkg, "$"), full.names = TRUE) : 
  invalid 'pattern' regular expression
```

What does this error mean?
the link to the script is: http://mzmatch.sourceforge.net/metabolomics/Processing_Code.R

But I changed few lines at the beginning:

```
library ("D:\\java projects\\RScriptRunning\\R\\win-library\\2.15\\mzmatch.R")
mzmatch.init (6000)
setwd ("D:\\R_Script\\raw")
```

Comment: Could you please show the code used that causes this error, not just the message? (In particular, we need to see what is in `pkg`)

Comment: we need a reproducible example please ... this question can't be answered without any context. See http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000 . In particular, the error means that the `pkg` variable contained a string that doesn't make a legitimate regular expression (see `?regexp`), but we can't really say much without context.

Answer (score 3):

**Completely rewrote** my answer, as [the first version](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/11917487/revisions) missed the relevant point.

When you read an error message like this, a call to `traceback()` will tell you *where* the error occurred. In this case it will most likely identify the `find.package` function, which somehow got called from the `library` function. It constructs a path name from a package name, and does not escape the package name. So symbols which have a special meaning in regular expressions (likely the backslash) will render this regular expression invalid, thus the error message.

The reason is that you attempt to load a library using the full path name of one of its files. **Libraries are loaded by package name only** (most likely `library(mzmatch)` in your case). You can use `source("C:\\some\\path")` to load and execute R source code from a given path, but I'd not suggest doing so for an installed library.

Comment: The problem could be in the "mzmatch.R" package used in the script.

Comment: As someone downvoted this answer, I'd be happy to see a comment informing me and others about the reason for that vote.

Comment: The downvote might have been related to what Joshua Ulrich mentioned - before you edited the post you were only assuming that the error was in the code and that the user would need to change something in the gsub - but it was most likely due to a call to a function in the package used.